# Is Google Analytics considered a tracker that violates user privacy?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, tracking, privacy

I like having Analytics on my site for all the great stats it provides, but I am aware that my customers don't necessarily want to be tracked.

But my understanding is that GA isn't a "tracker" in the same way that, say, the Facebook beacon (that follows you all over the web) is. I am not allowed to send any personally-identifiable information (PII) to GA, like a URL with someone's email address in it. I know that all data I give to GA is anonymous, per their rules.

I guess I just want to understand why people are against GA on a web site and in particular, if it's "tracking" the user or violating any privacy.

Comment: I changed your terminology of "tracking pixel".  A tracking pixel is a 1x1 transparent image included in your page but loaded from a site set up to collect statistics from it.   Almost nobody uses pixels for tracking these days.  Almost all trackers are JavaScript based now.   Better terminology would just be "tracker."  Facebook calls theirs a "beacon."

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that - already I'm learning something. ;-)